# WCF Service exposing DTO or Entity

Tags: wpf, wcf, model

I have read questions and answers about this topic but I still have some question without answer.

If I create a method to convert Entity to DTO i'll run into some circular calling methods (probably caused by errors in Model), for example:

**Product** class has a property **Supplier** that point to a Supplier class that contains a List property with all the products supplied.. So if i create a **GetProductDTO(Product entity)** method that return a ProductDTO class i'll have to call **GetSupplierDTO(Supplier entity)** for each product, but this last method must call GetProductDTO for every product in the list of products supplied...

In summary, i'm searching for a pattern or best practice to create a EntityModel -> WCF Service -> Prism WPF application.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for DTO purposes you might simply choose not to serialize any "parent" properties. Often, you see DTO with *no* navigation properties except for **strictly** associated data (for example, order-header => order-detail, but you wouldn't have order-header => customer - just the customer's key; you'd fetch the customer separately). With this approach, there is a unidirectional path to serialize/deserialize any graph, and it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, this can be the rapid solution... next in the client I have to re-create the graph? So in each side i have to convert EF->DTO  and DTO->EF ?

Comment: Yes. That's what you have to do.

Comment: Damn, it's not the answer i was waiting for... :-)